# VS Code - Tabs reload when switching

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I switch tabs on VS Code the content of the tab is being reloaded. It might not be a problem when developing on local machine, but I'm connected to a remote a machine using WinSShFS.

Can I cache the file locally and only access the remote server on save and first load?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not at this time. When you switch to a tab that has a file from a network drive open, Visual Studio Code reloads said file. That's an issue with the way Visual Studio Code's tabbing system was originally designed

The Visual Studio Code team has [an item in their backlog](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13665) that includes this specific "problem". It would appear that this isn't a priority for them yet, so a time-frame for when you could expect a fix for this, cannot yet be provided.

Comment: It is not a "problem" it is a problem! rendering the VS Code useless for me.
I was one of the people who reported the issue to them but I found out about their github account only after posting here. Yet your answer is correct so I'll accept it.

Comment: I understand your frustration Eden, I really do. I too have to deal with similar issues on a daily basis. The reason I described it using "problem", is because it's not a bug, it's a design flaw.